# How to store Current date and time in ISODATE format in mongodb php?

Tags: datetime, time, php-mongodb, gmt, isodate

I want to store the current GMT date and time in ISODate format in mongodb.
Similarly to this

```
ISODate("2012-07-26T17:43:25.678Z")
```

I want to store the result in mongodb in the above mentioned format(it should be a ISODate object). How to generate such a format in using php?

Answer (score 0):

I think DateTime will fit into an ISODate, but you might also want to consider http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php.

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoDate: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php

Example in this page:

```
<?php

// save a date to the database
$collection->save(array("ts" => new MongoDate()));

$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-15 00:00:00"));
$end = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-30 00:00:00"));

// find dates between 1/15/2010 and 1/30/2010
$collection->find(array("ts" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end)));

?>
```